# How can i add a button box to scene view ? (Not ui)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("m"))
            Debug.Log("menu");
    }
}
```

First the Update function is not calling in scene view.
And second how can i add in the Start or in other event a box menu like ? For example:

```
GUILayout.Window(0, new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100), (id)=> {
            GUILayout.Button("A Button");
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneGUI : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Window/Scene GUI/Enable")]
    public static void Enable()
    {
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate += OnScene;
        Debug.Log("Scene GUI : Enabled");
    }

    [MenuItem("Window/Scene GUI/Disable")]
    public static void Disable()
    {
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate -= OnScene;
        Debug.Log("Scene GUI : Disabled");
    }

    private static void OnScene(SceneView sceneview)
    {
        Handles.BeginGUI();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Destroy Objects", GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.Height(100)))
        {

        }

        Handles.EndGUI();
    }
}
```